# Connecting MongoDB & Java via Eclipes

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, bson, mongo-java

I am trying to create a simple connection and insert a document to local MongoDB instance using java (eclipse 4.7.1a). MongoDB is up & running and able to do operations via "Compass" as well.

```
          package com;
          import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
          import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
          import com.mongodb.DB;
          import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
          import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
          import com.mongodb.DBObject;
          import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
          import java.net.UnknownHostException;
          import java.util.Date;
          import java.util.List;
          import java.util.Arrays;

          public class connectToDB {
               public static void main( String args[] ) {

          try{

             // To connect to mongodb server
             MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017                                       
          );

             // Now connect to your databases
             DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
             System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

             // if collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you    
             DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
             System.out.println("Collection coll selected successfully");

             // insert  
             List<Integer> books = Arrays.asList(27464, 747854);
             DBObject documents = new BasicDBObject("_id", "jo")
                                         .append("name", "Jo Bloggs")
                                         .append("address", new BasicDBObject("street", "123 Fake St")
                                                                      .append("city", "Faketon")
                                                                      .append("state", "MA")
                                                                      .append("zip", 12345))
                                         .append("books", books);
             coll.insert(documents);
             System.out.println("Document added to Collection coll successfully");

             // update
             BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
             query.put("name", "Xo");

             BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
             newDocument.put("name", "Jo Bloggs-updated");

             BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
             updateObj.put("$set", newDocument);

             coll.update(query, updateObj);
             System.out.println("Document updated to Collection coll successfully");

             // find - search
             BasicDBObject searchQuery1 = new BasicDBObject();
             searchQuery1.put("name", "mkyong");
             DBCursor cursor = coll.find(searchQuery1);
             System.out.println("Selection from Collection coll done successfully");
             while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
             }

             // delete
             BasicDBObject searchQuery2 = new BasicDBObject();
             searchQuery2.put("name", "Xo");
             coll.remove(searchQuery2);
             System.out.println("Document deleted from Collection mycol2 successfully");

          }catch(Exception e){
             System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          }
       }
```

}

But when executed, ends with following error in eclipse.

```
Nov 01, 2017 2:19:31 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE,                 
requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', 
maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.bson.BsonDocument.clone()Lorg/bson/BsonDocument;
at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.
createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:159)
at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.
createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:149)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.<init>
 (InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:37)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.
create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:58)
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:359)
at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>
(SingleServerCluster.java:52)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.
createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:147)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:726)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:720)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:290)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:285)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:281)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:186)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:163)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:153)
at com.connectToDB.main(connectToDB.java:25)
```

MongoDB version : v3.4.9
Following jar files used. bson 3.0.4.jar & mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar

Could anyone help me out with on why this is been giving this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your codes are working perfectly before you use your MongoDB code run simple hello world program,

```
        public class connectToDB {
           public static void main( String args[] ) {

                  System.out.println("Hello world");

                }
          }
```

if it works then put your MongoDB codes in the main and run it again. in case if it does not work then the first thing you need to learn "how to use Eclipse IDE?" before you jump into the database.

Here is the result of your codes.
[image]

here is how your data looks like in the database. 
[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, Thx for the comment. I am a pl/sql guy so trying out stuff these days. On your advice i have tested with simple java code with main and it works. But soon as i define a Mongo DB client object error comes back again.  
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );  Any issue with the jar files i use?

Comment: If I am not mistaking maybe problem is with your Mongodb jar library, okay remove all Mongodb libraries and download jar file from here, [Mongodb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.2) remember do not add any additional jar after that , it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted 'bson-3.0.2.jar' from referenced libraries of the code, and it works.
As the error message said,

> NoSuchMethodError:
> org.bson.BsonDocument.clone()Lorg/bson/BsonDocument;

it seems that certain method dependency has been crashed between bson jar and mongodb java driver.